# How to exclude (-) sign by appending it to the next operand when 2 or more operators are entered consecutively in a operation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a calculator app using ReactJS. Most of the things are working expectedly. However I want the (-) sign to be appended to the next operand when 2 or more operators are entered consecutively e.g., something like this should happen: the sequence "5 * - 5" = should produce an output of "-25" : rather than '0'.
Below is the snippet for reference

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      previous: "",
      current: "",
      operation: "",
    };
  }

  clear = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      previous: "",
      current: "0",
      operation: null,
    }));
  };

  delete = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      current: prevState.current.slice(0, -1),
    }));
  };

  appendNumber = (number) => {
    const { current } = this.state;
    if (current === "0") {
      this.delete();
    }
    if (number === "." && current.includes(".")) return;
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        current: prevState.current + number,
      })
    );
  };

  chooseOperation = (op) => {
    const { previous, current, operation } = this.state;
    if (previous !== "" && current !== "") {
      this.compute();
    }

    // if (operation !== "" && op === "-" && previous !== "" && current === "") {
    //   this.setState((prevState) => ({
    //     current: "-",
    //     operation: prevState.operation,
    //   }));
    // } else {

    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        operation: op,
        previous:
          prevState.current === "" ? prevState.previous : prevState.current,
        current: "",
      })
    );

    // }
  };

  compute = () => {
    let computation;
    const { previous, current, operation } = this.state;
    const prev = parseFloat(previous);
    const curr = parseFloat(current);
    if (isNaN(previous) || isNaN(current)) return;
    let factorial = (n) => (n === 1 ? n : n * factorial(n - 1));
    switch (operation) {
      case "+":
        computation = prev + curr;
        break;
      case "-":
        computation = prev - curr;
        break;
      case "*":
        computation = prev * curr;
        break;
      case "÷":
        computation = prev / curr;
        break;
      case "!":
        computation = factorial(prev);
        break;
      case "√":
        computation = Math.sqrt(prev);
        break;
      case "log":
        computation = Math.log(prev);
        break;
      case "sin":
        computation = Math.sin(prev * (Math.PI / 180));
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    this.setState({
      current: computation,
      operation: "",
      previous: "",
    });
  };
```

As you can see in the commented portion of chooseOperation method I tried to implement the said logic by conditionally updating the state parameters, here is how it looked like

```
chooseOperation = (op) => {
    const { previous, current, operation } = this.state;
    if (previous !== "" && current !== "") {
      this.compute();
    }

    if (operation !== "" && op === "-" && previous !== "" && current === "") {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        current: "-",
        previous: prevState.previous,
        operation: prevState.operation,
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(
        (prevState) => ({
          operation: op,
          previous:
            prevState.current === "" ? prevState.previous : prevState.current,
          current: "",
        })
      );
    }
  };
```

However I am getting errors with this version. Even though I was able to perform a simple calculation like '8 * - 5 = -40',but the program failed on longer operations containing chained operations.

UPDATE : the chained operations are working expectedly now after updating the if conditional inside chooseOperation (adding `&& current === ""` within the parenthesis of if block).

However the test suite for the project by freecodecamp says a sequence like "5 * - + 5" = should produce an output of "10".

PS: This is the last test I'm stuck with for this project

Comment: I think you might be confusing the negative sign and the minus operation. If you use a regular calculator and enter `8 * - 5` you won't get `-40`. Some calcs have a `+/-` key to change the number sign

Comment: As you can see I don't have a parameter for sign in the state object. When the button containing "-" in the jsx is clicked the operation of subtraction kicks in. However I need to achieve the aforementioned functionality, preferably without adding any extra parameter as most of the other things work expectedly

Comment: How can you tell the difference if the user wants to subtract or change the number sign?

Comment: Please see the conditional of chooseOperation method in the second snippet, if the operation and previous parameters aren't empty strings and then "-" is clicked we leave both parameters unchanged and append that "-" sign to the current parameter.
That didn't work for chained operations like 3 + 5 * 6 - 2 / 4 though

Comment: Please show the specific error message, and the input that led to that error message.  It would be very helpful if you set up a simple CodeSandbox (or similar) with the above code so that people could see it in action and replicate the error(s) you are seeing.

Comment: the codepen link to the project : https://codepen.io/donjoe21915/pen/jOJOzXJ

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question (or replace your old question if you have no answers), don't just tack on an UPDATE to your existing question.

Comment: @GregFenton We prefer people use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that the code ends up on this site rather than elsewhere.